# Javascript editing in Eclipse-03 - set default editor

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Having trouble with Javascript file editing after moving to Eclipse 2021-03.

I have seen similar related issues discussed elsewhere, for example: [Eclipse 2020-06 Javascript - Syntax Hightlighting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509948/eclipse-2020-06-javascript-syntax-hightlighting-not-working)

The "answer" appears to be to set the default editor to "Generic Text Editor".  However the default editor is set to "Text Editor" and this appears to be hard-wired.

After installing WDT, there is a Content Type Text->JavaScript Source File. This  has Text Editor and Generic Text Editor as the associated editors, and these entries cannot be removed.  When I click on a .js file in the Project Explorer it opens with Text Editor.

Why is this so hard?  And is there a better JavaScript editor for Eclipse?

Comment: It sounds like you have not actually attempted to set the default as in that question's most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out. I could just delete the question but maybe someone will be having the same UI blindness that I was experiencing.

The trick is you have to specify the default from among the current associated editors.  Go to Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations; then select the editor you want as default and click the default button.  The name of the editor will now have (default) appended to it.

[image]